# Ноw to configure mission sequence for propagate until desired date in GMAT?

Tags: astrodynamics, gmat, propagation

In GMAT, I have a state of satellite for a date (for example, 24.04.2022). Now, I need to propagate its motion for some days forward, until selected date (say, 29.04.2022).
I added Propagation into Mission Sequence, and in ParameterSelectDialog, for selected sat added parameter UTCModJulian, and set it equal to 59698.000000 (i.e., UT 00:00:00.0 29.04.2022 - by analog, same as we do for a parameter ElapsedDate).
But, GMAT doesn't stop after reached selected time, and simulation continues unstoppably. I'm confused. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is through some built-in GMAT function code.  Here's a snip from a functional script:

```
    Create Variable epoch;
    Create String when;
    
    BeginMissionSequence;

    when = ConvertTime('UTCGregorian', 'UTCModJulian', '02 Jan 2000 12:00:00.000')
    epoch = Str2num(when);
    
    Propagate DefaultProp(DefaultSC) {DefaultSC.UTCModJulian = epoch};
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I found what was wrong. In GMAT integrated help mentioned, that GMAT used non-standart MJD offset. For standart MJD, offset is **2400000.5**, for GMAT MJD offset is **2430000.0**.