# Difference between UTCGregorian and A1ModJulian or UTCModJulian in GMAT?

Tags: nasa, gmat

I have a question related to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/59051/%D0%9D%D0%BEw-to-configure-mission-sequence-for-propagate-until-desired-date-in-gmat/59063#59063).
I have computed several propulsive maneuvers required for GEO orbit acquisition using the Target feature of NASA GMAT 2022a and saved them to a maneuver list report using the *.Epoch.UTCGregorian variable.
Now I want to reload this information and perturb this maneuvers to see the effect of thrust vector error and orientation missalignments but when I load the maneuvers and use the convert function from string to num as indicated in the answer I found out that the deltaV required for changing for example the apogee is not the same as before and whilerevisiting the classical orbit elements reports I found that the loaded maneuver is actually changing the elements 212 minutes after the target maneuver epoch and if I sustract this value from the loaded maneuver epoch then the maneuver performs as expected... is this behaviour normal? I dont think so...
Thanks in advance for your thoughts on this...